Authentication method for Django rest framework to mitigate XSS and CSRF attacks
I am using the Django Rest Framework for my backend and React for my front, and they are served in different domains and subdomains, and now I am completely confused about what I should do to secure my APIs from XSS and CSRF attacks. I wish to use simple-JWT for the application, but my research showed that it is vulnerable to XSS. And if I store them in  http-only cookies, they can't be accessible on the front end to add them to the  authorization header, and it would be like using sessions. What should I do? And what is the best practice for securing APIs?
I also used dj-rest-auth package, but it was a little bit tricky, if someone used this module it would be grate to hear the experience.
I would be glad to hear your suggestions.

This question is similar to: Where to store JWT in browser? How to protect against CSRF?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you know i didn't get my answer and i just became more confused , i need some one to explain entirely and give me some examples or codes @ChukwujiobiCanon
